# Problem with iTune in app purchase!

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am setting up an in-app-purchase system in my app. I have registered the in-app-purchase at iTune connect. And here comes my code:

This is the code for requesting product info:

```
- (void) requestProductData {   
    SKProductsRequest *request= 
        [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: 
         [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.myapp.id"]] autorelease];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

This is the code for receiving the product info:
(basically I did nothing but trying to print it out)

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    SKProduct *product = [myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
    [numberFormatter release];
    NSLog(@"Product 0 : %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", product.productIdentifier, product.localizedDescription, product.localizedTitle, product.priceLocale.localeIdentifier, formattedString);
    [request autorelease];
}
```

I have applied the delegate:

```
@interface StoreObserver : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>{
```

I used a button to trigger `requestProductData`. By using breakpoints, I was sure it got called. However, `productsRequest` was never called. I made sure of the connectivity too.

Does anybody hava any clue?

Comment: Are you calling this from the device or from the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is here:

```
- (void) requestProductData {   
    SKProductsRequest *request= 
        [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: 
         [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.myapp.id"]] autorelease]; //<- here
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

You should never autorelease the SKProductsRequest. I am so stupid to make this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You skipped a part of the howto I guess

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

Comment: Thanks. I am giving it a try. I thought SKPaymentQueue only have something to do with SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

Comment: Good point, you may be right about that. Have you tried removing the app from your device? How long have you waited since setting up the product id's in iTunes Connect? Are you using a sandbox account? Have you uploaded a binary to iTunes Connect?

Comment: Or just visit this great walkthrough yourself: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: To answer your questions:
1. No, but I will try removing the app and see how it goes.
2. I have waited for 2 days since setting up the id in iTunes Connect. But I uploaded the screenshot only 1 hour ago.
3. Yes, but I think requesting data has nothing to do with sandbox account, am I right?
4. Yes, a binary without in app purchase is already on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Hmm. You could also look at `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`. But such a situation should have crashed your app already, since you would be accessing element 0 of an empty array `response.products`. Still, you should log that one as well.